# Unicode character with flume

Tags: csv, hadoop, unicode, flume

I'm trying to put a CSV file into HDFS using flume, file contains some unicode characters also.

Once the file is there in HDFS I tried to view the content, but unable to see the records properly.

**File content**

```
Name    age  sal    msg

Abc     21  1200    Lukè éxample àpple

Xyz     23  1400    er stîget ûf mit grôzer
```

**Output in console**

I did `hdfs dfs -get /flume/events/csv/events.1234567`

Below is the output

```
Name,age,sal,msg

Abc,21,1200,Luk��xample��pple

Xyz,23,1400,er st�get �f mit gr�zer
```

Does flume supports Unicode characters? If not how it can be handled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Flume does support Unicode character. You can read your Unicode file using flume and transfer data to HDFS. This looks like some other issue.Change hdfs.fileType to DataStream and see if you can properly read output.

```
a1.sources = r1
a1.channels = c1
a1.sinks = k1

#source
a1.sources.r1.type = exec
a1.sources.r1.command = tail -F /root/user/shashi/unicode/french.txt
a1.sources.r1.restart = true

#sink

a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = /flume/events/
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = events-
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.round = true
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
#channel
a1.channels.c1.type = memory

#connect
a1.sources.r1.channels = c1
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
```

Here is a smaple configuration that i have used.